# Get Error "Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in"

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

[Here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8rmG.png)

I wan't to add text "You" Before msg but it getting error.
my php code :

($outgoing_id == $row2['outgoing_msg_id']) ? $you = "You: " : $you = "";

Comment: that's ridiculous to provide the error without the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this error returned due to the nullable of the $row2
this besides the wrong format of the condition as @DamianCabelloJiménez mentioned
we can add a little edit to @DamianCabelloJiménez answer to handle the nullable case

```
$you = (isset($row2['outgoing_msg_id']) && $outgoing_id == $row2['outgoing_msg_id']) ?  "You: " : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong if format

```
$result = condition ? valueTrue : valueFalse;
```

Your if should be like this:

```
$you = ($outgoing_id == $row2['outgoing_msg_id']) ?  "You: " : "";
```

Comment: the error is still there, but if i delete that line the error is gone

Comment: can you share a screenshot from your data.php?, the error was in line 15, maybe wrong array access.

Maybe your $row2['outgoing_msg_id'] was null and can´t access to read it